# Exercise about linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, inverse

For $X$ Banach, I have to show that if $T\in\mathfrak{L}(X)$ and $||T||_{\mathfrak{L}(X)}<1$ then exists $(I-T)^{-1}$ and 
$$
(I-T)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n. 
$$
For the existence of $(I-T)^{-1}$ I proved that $\ker(I-T)=\{0\}$. But for the second point of the proof I don't know how to proceed. I know that this is the geometric series and $||T||_{\mathfrak{L}(X)}<1$, but I'm not sure this is enough.

Comment: Would probably help if your sum started at $n=0$. :D How about you just compute $(I-T)(series)$? If $(I-T)(series) = (series)(I-T) = I$, then it follows that $(I-T)^{-1} = series$. Showing that the series converges would also be relevant, but I think you know how to do that.

Comment: If I consider $(I-T)(series)=T^0$ even if $T$ is an application is correct $T^0=1$? (Probably a silly question..)

Comment: If $(I-T)(series) = I$ then you know that $I-T$ is surjective and that $(series)$ is injective ; you don't know that both are bijective and inverse of each other. However in this case you can easily compute both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this $$(I-T)\circ \sum_{j=0}^{n} T^j =I-T^{n+1} $$ and $$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} T^j \right)\circ (I-T)=I-T^{n+1} .$$

Comment: And then I show that $\lim T^{n+1}=0$ using the information about its $||\cdot||$?

Comment: Yes, take the limit on both sides.